# Professor Roman gives unusual math quiz ahead of

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

His usual Monday Morning 8am class.
This is for extra AAA credits.

$A$, $B$, $C$ are distinct digits.

$AA$, $BA$, $BBAAA$, $CBBBAB$ are distinct numbers.

Please deduce these with concise reasoning from the given relation:

Rearrangement of the terms in the Equation gives interesting Prime Relationship.

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{AA^{BA}-\big(BBAAA\cdot CBBBAB\big) = A}$$

Comment: Thx for the edit..looks better

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: **Comment proving that actual 'digits' are impossible.** The term $BBAAA\cdot CBBBAB$ has a maximum order of magnitude of $(4+5)+1=10$ where the $1$ is due to carrying. However, if $B>0$, $AA^{BA}$ will have order of magnitude of at least $11$ since its minimum value is $11^{11}$. We cannot have $A=0$ based on the assumption that $0^0$ is not allowed. Thus $B=0$. 

This leaves us with the expression $$AA^A-(AAA\cdot C000A0)\equiv(11A)^A-111A\cdot(100000C+10A)=A$$ and we can see that $A^A$ must have the same last digit as $A$, forcing $A=5,6,9$. Checking each value proves their impossibility.

Comment: Sure..statement regarding prime relationship gives valuable clue...if terms are rearranged..this is the first number that fails it..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The answer uses Roman numerals, as this is a Prof. Roman puzzle.
>
>  A = I
>  B = X
>  C = L
>
>  This gives the equation:
>
>  $2^{11} - 23*89 = 1$
>
>  Reasoning: after guessing roman numerals were involved, the pattern CBBBAB forces AB to be IX or XC or CM etc.  This is because BAB forces A to be a one type digit, but BBB means that B can't be a five type digit because something like VVVIV doesn't exist (it would be XVIV).  Taking the simplest case of A=I B=X gives $2^{11} - 23 * (C+39) = 1$, which means that C must be 50, or L.

Comment: Prof. Roman congratulates you for your fast thinking and awards you extra credit of AAA points..

Comment: @Uvc do you mean B? how can you award AAA points???

Comment: I mean B..thx..regarding lateral thinking..probably debatable?  I wanted to hint that it is not regular number substitution for the letters

Comment: AAA is 3 points?

Comment: After solving..it is 111 points...in the puzzle it should mean triple A credits rather than points strictly to avoid confusion